# Select last 3 consecutive rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I keep staring at this query that runs in a stored procedure getting more confused.

I have a table that looks like this...

```
AsofDate       Database_Name      Mirroring_Sate
DateTime       Database1          Synchronized 
DateTime       Database2          Suspended
DateTime       Database3          Disconnected
DateTime       Database1          Synchronized 
DateTime       Database2          Synchronized
DateTime       Database3          Disconnected
DateTime       Database1          Synchronized 
DateTime       Database2          Synchronized
DateTime       Database3          Disconnected
```

So I have a job that runs and records the mirroring status in this table for 3 databases every 15 minutes.  I need a query that will for any one database name for 3 consecutive checks if the mirroring status is not equal to Synchronized.

So if for example Database1 at 3pm, then 3.15pm, then at 3.30pm was in a disconnected state, this is what I need to know.  What I am doing at the moment is looking at the whole table and if the count for any one database in a state other than synchronized is 3 or more then I'm taking an acion which isn't quite what I want.  I only want to do this for the last 3 checks and that's it.

Here's my query as it stands.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.U_MirroringStatus WITH (NOLOCK)
            where mirroring_state_desc <> 'SYNCHRONIZED'
            GROUP BY database_name
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= @MirroringStatusViolationCountForAlert
            )
```

Any help / advice would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this will do what you need:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM (SELECT TOP 3 ms.*
                 FROM dbo.U_MirroringStatus WITH (NOLOCK)
                 WHERE database_name = @DatabaseName
                 ORDER BY AsOfDate DESC
                ) ms
            WHERE mirroring_state_desc <> 'SYNCHRONIZED'
            HAVING COUNT(*) >= @MirroringStatusViolationCountForAlert
           )
```

In the text, you specify that you want this for a single database, which is why I added the `where`.

Comment: thankyou.  I basically want to group the check by database name.  The query needs to check for all databases, not a particular one.  So if Database1 is disconnected the last 3 checks it will do something

Comment: I've updated the table so you can see what it looks like. So the query should return database 3 as the last 3 checks have been disconnected for this db.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Database_Name 
  from ( select AsofDate, Database_Name, Mirroring_Sate 
                ROW_NUMBER ( ) Over (partition by Database_Name order by AsofDate desc) as row 
       ) as xx 
 where Mirroring_Sate <> 'SYNCHRONIZED'
   and row <= 3 
 group by Database_Name 
having count(*) = 3
```

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: I'm getting the below error with this query.  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: needs to be ROW_NUMBER ( )